# How do I link Tumblr to /domain?

Tags: tumblr

I have two tumblr blogs. I have already linked one to my domain name e.g example.com. I have another tumblr account and I would like to link it to the same domain name but /shirts. E,g example.com/shirts.

I use godaddy.com

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need to create a subdomain like 'shirts.example.com', as you've given most DNS control of the domain over to Tumblr as I'm sure they had you change your name servers. You may still be able to create a subdomain in your control panel though.

An end-user wouldn't expect a "directory" to lead to a different site anyway.

EDIT:
To redirect to 'example.com/shirts' from [Tumblr support](http://support.tumblr.com/post/23625479768/how-to-make-redirect-pages):

1. Click “Add a Page.”
2. Type a Page URL after the slash (/). For example, if you’re
   redirecting to Twitter, you could type /mytwitter. If you’re
   redirecting to Facebook, you could use /myfacebook.
3. Change the Page Type from Standard Layout to Redirect.
4. Type or paste the web address that the Page will redirect to.
5. Check the box that says “Show a link to this page” and give the Page
   a title in the field next to the checkbox (e.g. My Twitter or My
   Facebook).
6. Click “Create page.”

Comment: @MichaelSórm If it answers your question, you can accept the answer by ticking the check next to the upvote count.

Comment: But is it it possible to have it example.com/shirts?

Comment: @MichaelSórm it is, it would be much more complicated for you. You would need to customize your DNS records instead of simply switching the nameservers to those of Tumblr. "Premium" DNS features aren't included by default with GoDaddy either, so you may incur extra charge as well...

Comment: @MichaelSórm actually, I just checked the Tumblr docs and there should be a simpler, free solution through them for you. Check the edits to my answer.